# How can I use sub fields in wordpress meta_query for wp query args?

Tags: php, wordpress, args

Hi all I'm trying to ad a meta_query to my wp query args.

Here is my post meta:

```
$post_options = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'post_options')[0];
print_r($post_options);
```

which produces an array like this:

```
Array ( [on_demand] => true [featured_video] => https://example.com/1234 )
```

Here is my code, the normal loop works fine but breaks when I add the meta_query:

```
//helper function from https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/
function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'post_options_%", "meta_key LIKE 'post_options_%", $where);
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');

    $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'order' => 'DESC',
     'meta_query'    => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'post_options_%_on_demand',
                'value'   => 'true',
                'compare' => '='
            )
        )  
    );
    
        // The Query
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: is the `on_demand` field a `meta_key` or nested in serialized data?

Comment: print_r($post_options); returns multiple arrays like the one shown. So I guess that means its nested inside  'post_options')[0].